# How to properly link mkl interfaces with fortls

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, blas, intel-mkl

In my project I'm doing massive use of the `blas` subroutines under the `mkl` implementation, I have no problems in compiling the project thanks to the `Intel Advisor`, but I can't get `fortls` to recognize the interface of the functions.

I tried to modify the `Modern Fortran` extensions settings adding to the include path `/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/include/` where there is the file `mkl_blas.fi` which contains all the interfaces (the `.mod` files are in the subfolder `mkl/intel64/ilp64`) but the linter highlights in blue the line `use blas95`, saying that it can't be found in the project, and still asks for the `external` or an explicit interface for `dgemm`.

Answer (score 1):

`fortls` cannot read `.mod` files since every compiler vendor uses a custom format to create them; it can only understand sources. If you have the sources for MKL you can add them to the files `fortls` needs to parse by editing the parsing options see docs:
https://fortls.fortran-lang.org/options.html#sources-file-parsing

This will allow you to hover, peek, goto etc. to the MKL interfaces. You will probably have to set the `.fi` extension as valid Fortran sources.

That being said, the linter and the language server (fortls) are 2 different things and hence have different options. The linter uses a proper compiler (by default gfortran) to mock-compile your code. I would guess that the .mod files have been compiled with `ifx` and not `gfortran` so:

- set your linter to ifx
- include the directories containing the .mod files (you can use regex) to the linter

Your settings should look something like this;

```
{
    "fortran.linter.compiler": "ifx",
    // only necessary if ifx is not in your PATH
    "fortran.linter.compilerPath": "/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/latest/linux/bin/intel64/ifx",
    "fortran.linter.includePaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**", // your source files, you might not want this depending on your project
        "/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/intel64/ilp64/**" // location of .mod files
    ],
    "fortran.fortls.directories": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**", // your source files
        "/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/include/**" // location of MKL interfaces
    ],
    "fortran.fortls.suffixes": [
        ".fi",
    ]
}
```